# wpf combobox style

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

Can anyone tell by looking at this style will cause a combobox with it applied to stretch as wide as the screen unless you give it an explicit width?

```
<Style x:Key="ThemedComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2,25,2"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Name="comboToggleStyle">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="Pressed"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="gloss" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="NormalState">
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_BackgroundGradient}"/>
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Stroke="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_StrokeGradient}"/>
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_HighlightGradient}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="MouseOverState" Opacity="0">
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_BackgroundGradient}"/>
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Stroke="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_StrokeGradient}"/>
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_MouseOverBackgroundGradient}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="PressedState" Opacity="0">
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_PressedBackgroundGradient}"/>
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Stroke="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_StrokeGradient}"/>
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_PressedHighlightGradient}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="DisabledState" Opacity="0">
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_DisabledBackgroundGradient}"/>
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Stroke="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_StrokeGradient}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="contentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                            <Path Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,6" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Data="M100,12.903966 C59.117226,15.115555 23.108757,29.203354 -1.2437163E-14,60 L-3.2684966E-13,0 C12,-2.8610229E-06 100,0 100,0" x:Name="gloss" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_GlossGradient}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard/>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentPresenterBorder">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-1" x:Name="DropDownToggle" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_GreyStateBackground}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_StrokeGradient}" Background="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_BackgroundGradient}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press">
                                <Path Height="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,0" x:Name="BtnArrow" Width="8" Stretch="Uniform" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z " Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_GreyStateBackground}"/>
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,3,23,3" x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" Fill="#A5000000" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3"/>
                    <Popup IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom" x:Name="Popup" Focusable="False" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Border Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" Background="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_PopupBackgroundGradient}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_StrokeGradient}">
                                <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="0" Padding="1" Foreground="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_Selected}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few things, the problem was the Path.

```
 <Path Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,6" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Data="M100,12.903966 C59.117226,15.115555 23.108757,29.203354 -1.2437163E-14,60 L-3.2684966E-13,0 C12,-2.8610229E-06 100,0 100,0" x:Name="gloss" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_GlossGradient}"/>
```

I removed the Stretch="Fill" and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

The default FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment property (which isn't set above) is `Stretch`. You need to set it to `Left`, `Center` or `Right` to keep it from stretching.

Often, the real solution to a problem like this isn't to change the HorizontalAlignment property of the control though, it's to set the width of the element containing your ComboBox to Auto, or fix it's HorizontalAlignment property to something other than `Stretch`.